# SP2013 : Search Results WP is showing EVERY documents, even when there is no results

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, search, search-results

let me explain that difficult title...

**What i want :**

I want a search page with a Search Zone WP and a Search Results WP. That is easy.
Then, i want the search results to show only the right item through documents content types in this active site collection. Not bad too, right ?

**What i have :**

I have 7 documents in all this active site collection.
A document named "XZYU", containing "XZYU" is uploaded into the document library. So, that means 8 documents.
I tape "XZYU" into the search Zone, and i have the results : the 8 documents are showing, even if 7 of them do no have any "XZYU" in them nor in their title.
The first to show is XZYU, with the XZYU written in bold. The other have nothing in bold (that's normal)
I try with "ABCPM" (which is not likely to appear in any document), and... every 8 documents are showing, without any bold, but they are showing !

**Instead, normally** i should have the SP message like "No result found for your search...".

Did this already happened to somebody here ?

Could you give me some tips to resolve this ?

Thanks a lot.

Gaëlle

Answer (score 1):

Okay, finally solved this in no time after posting this thread !

**Here was my Query :**

"path:https://mySiteCollection" (FileExtension:doc OR FileExtension:docx OR FileExtension:xls OR FileExtension:xlsx OR FileExtension:ppt OR FileExtension:pptx OR FileExtension:pdf)

**Here is now my query :**

{SearchBoxQuery} path:https://mySiteCollection  (FileExtension:doc OR FileExtension:docx OR FileExtension:xls OR FileExtension:xlsx OR FileExtension:ppt OR FileExtension:pptx OR FileExtension:pdf)

The {SearchBoxQuery} is essential to link your search zone !

Comment: Couldn't you also just use the Documents Result Source?

Comment: Hello Matthew,
That is what i used for the search. it really showed me only documents, but not restricted to what i typed in the search zone.